# Prevent returns from ajax.php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, return

In my ajax.php has:

```
   if(urlvar(2) == 'uploadphoto'){
       do... echo '<img... />';
   }
```

But this functions is only called by a jquery, returning on a specific div.

But if I visit the URL: [http://localhost/projectname/ajax/uploadphoto], this page returns the result of function with some erros (because the parameters are sent by jquery)

How I can prevent returns, if the file is accessed without jquery?

*SOLVED:

Use this function in functions that cannot be accessed without jquery method.

```
    function isHttpRequest()
    {
        if( @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest') {
            return true; //acessed by jquery
        }
        exit; // or return false -> from access the file without method
    }
```

Comment: You cannot reliably detect AJAX calls. The HTTP_X header is USUALLY present, but an AJAX request is an HTTP request like ANY OTHER. If someone wants to forge that header in their request, it is impossible for server-side code to detect that.

Comment: You should also consider returning a 404 instead of an empty response.

Answer (score 0):

When you access the file via jQuery, you write something like:

`method: "get"` or `method:"post"`  (The default, if not specified, is GET, I think)

So, at the beginning of your ajax.php - put:

```
if(!$_GET){

     //[...the ajax.php code, here ...]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally create a hash in every form
and i check if that hash is correct , this prevents people from submitting forms from other servers too and it may help in your situation
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/secure-your-forms-with-form-keys--net-4753
if the hash is wrong then it's abviously not coming from the form that it should come from

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `ajax.php` to check if the request is an ajax call.

```
if(empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) 
   || strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) !== 'xmlhttprequest') {
   // not an ajax request
} else {
    if(urlvar(2) == 'uploadphoto'){
      do... echo '<img... />';
    }
}
```

Or just check at the beginning of `ajax.php`

Comment: user3280126, YES!

I make this:

  function isHttpRequest()
  {
   if( @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest') {
    return true; //acessed by jquery
   }
   exit; // or return false -> from access the file without method
  }

Thanks and I hope this is of help to someone!

Comment: Glad to hear it helped!